# Color political map with the smallest number of colors

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to color political map with the smallest number of collors. The way I try to accomplish my goal right now is:

I fill the white space on map with flood algorithm. Then I check if reached the border by checking if color of the pixel is different from white and colors from my color list. If the colors are different then I am going further through the pixels the in same direction as before until I reach pixel in color from my list or white. When it is white or on the list but not the same color as the current color then I break the loop, when the color behind the border is the same as current color then I fill the country again with next color from list.
The problem is that the maps I am using often have borders like this:
[image]

Where the pixels behind border aren't really white. And my code is just going through those pixels back to the same country it has came from which results In getting next color from list, and later in Out of bound exception.
How can I resolve this issue? I don't want to create special map for my code, I would like it to work with any contour map.

Here is my code. It is pretty rough because I was experimenting with different approches. So any advices are wolcome :)

```
public class ImageColoring {

    private final int NORTH = 0;
    private final int SOUTH = 1;
    private final int WEST = 2;
    private final int EAST = 3;


    private final int[] COLORS = {-16726785,-65536,-15073025,-16711757,-16711919,-256,-417268,-455455,-5741663,-14194369,-14730152,-9885900};
    private List<Integer> colorList;

    private int colorCounter;
    private boolean shouldBreakRecursion = false;


    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImageColoring(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        colorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<COLORS.length;i++){
            colorList.add(COLORS[i]);
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage colorImage(){


        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
                    if (image.getRGB(i, j) == -1) {
                        fill(i, j, EAST);
                        colorCounter = 1;
                        //incrementCounter();
                    }

                }
            }
        }catch (StackOverflowError e){

        }

        return image;
    }


    private void fill(int x, int y, int direction){
        if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=image.getWidth() || y>=image.getHeight() || shouldBreakRecursion){
            return;
        }
        //if(image.getRGB(x,y)!=-1) return;
        if(image.getRGB(x,y)!=-1 && !colorList.contains(image.getRGB(x,y))){
            if(direction == NORTH){
                for(int i = y-1;i>0;i--){
                    if(image.getRGB(x,i) == COLORS[colorCounter]){
                        colorCounter++;
                        fill(x,y+1,SOUTH);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(image.getRGB(x,i) == -1  || colorList.contains(image.getRGB(x,i))) return;
                }
            }else if(direction == SOUTH){
                for(int i = y+1;i<image.getHeight();i++){
                    if(image.getRGB(x,i) == COLORS[colorCounter]){
                        colorCounter++;
                        fill(x,y-1,NORTH);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(image.getRGB(x,i) == -1  || colorList.contains(image.getRGB(x,i))) return;

                }
            }else if(direction == EAST){
                for(int i = x+1;i<image.getWidth();i++){

                    if(image.getRGB(i,y) == COLORS[colorCounter]){
                        System.out.println(image.getRGB(i,y) +" : "+COLORS[colorCounter]);
                        colorCounter++;
                        fill(x-1,y,WEST);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(image.getRGB(i,y) == -1  || colorList.contains(image.getRGB(i,y))) return;
                }
            }else if(direction == WEST){
                for(int i = x-1;i>0;i--){
                    if(image.getRGB(i,y) == COLORS[colorCounter]){
                        colorCounter++;
                        fill(x+1,y,EAST);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(image.getRGB(i,y) == -1  || colorList.contains(image.getRGB(i,y))) return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }else if(image.getRGB(x,y)!=-1) return;
        image.setRGB(x,y,COLORS[colorCounter]);



        fill(x+1,y, EAST);
        //fill(x-1,y,WEST);
        fill(x,y-1,NORTH);
        fill(x,y+1,SOUTH);

    }

    private void incrementCounter(){
        if(++colorCounter == COLORS.length) colorCounter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing you try will work in all cases.  Your map borders can become closer than your red circled example, pinching off the small region into its own area surrounded completely by dark outline pixels.   Things you could try would be a sharpening filter to your image; it might work for a fraction of your problem cases.  And edge following algorithm to trace out the regions will get just as confused by the blurry, close to touching borders.  You really need to get the borders as **path** objects, such as from an SVG file.  Bitmap images will always be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Everything @AJNeufeld says is true.  But...  If you really *have* to deal with the map data as depicted (you don't have access to a vector map, essentially) then one thing you could try is to refine how you detect a border.

Based on your image, a border is a 1px wide line drawn in #555555 (luminance 33%).  As long as you're crossing that border vertically or horizontally, you're guaranteed to cross a cell at least 50% of that color (approximately luminance 66%, or #a8a8a8).

Note I'm oversimplifying the effect of antialiasing slightly but not, I think in this case, by enough to cause a problem.

So I would specifically treat any gray shade between #55555 and #a8a8a8 as border, and ignore lighter gray shades (treat them as white).

As @AJNeufeld notes, this will likely create places where a border which loops back on itself pinches off a part of a region, but without vector data you're likely not going to be able to distinguish that from a separate area anyway.